# Azure DNS for country Domain

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I want to use my country domain which is mydomain.id after setting up in my azure DNS and domain provider, I still cannot validate my domain in App Service. I already double-check everything and I think my settings are already correct. Now I wonder can we use the Country domain in my azure DNS because I'm afraid if it's that the problem.

Comment: If your goal is to use your domain to point your app service, you don't actually need azure dns

Comment: Oh okay, so I just need to add A record in my DNS provider right that will point out to my  App Service IP right?

Comment: *And* tell the app service your domain since the IP is actually shared between multiple apps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

If it doesn't seem to resolve immediately, check the propagation status using dnschecker.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I assume you are using a public domain. As Martheen's comments mentioned that you just need to create DNS records to map your app service IP or hostname like `webapp.azurewebsites.net` in your DNS provider so that you can add **custom domains** in your App Service. This is [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

[Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-overview) is a hosting service for DNS domains that provides name resolution by using Microsoft Azure infrastructure. By hosting your domains in Azure, you can manage your DNS records by using the same credentials, APIs, tools, and billing as your other Azure services. You have the option to host your records on Azure DNS.

After adding the DNS records, you can use the local tool `nslookup` or websites `https://dnschecker.org/` to check the DNS propagation. It can take up to 72 hours to propagate worldwide, although it typically takes a few hours.